# Uniqueness of weak solution of a pde

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have proved the existence of weak solution in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ of the problem $-\Delta u + |u|^{p-1}u=f$ on $\Omega$ and $u=0$  on $\partial\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded and smooth domain of $R^n$, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $p>1$. I wonder which is the easiest technique to prove the unicity here. Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you used a variational method to find a weak solution (if not, look at [Using Energy method in finding weak solutions of PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156000/using-energy-method-in-finding-weak-solutions-of-pde?rq=1)).  In this case, the $u$ you found was the minimum of the energy
$$E[u] = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{2} |\nabla u |^2 + \frac{1}{p+1} |u|^{p+1} - fu \;dx$$

Moreover, $v$ solves
$$-\Delta v + |v|^{p-1} v = fv$$
if and only if the first variation of the energy at $v$, $\delta E[v]$, is zero.  We will show this can only happen at the minimizer $u$ by showing, roughly, that $E$ has positive Hessian.  In particular, we will show that the second variation of $E$, 
$$\delta^2E[u + t(u-v)](u-v) = \left.\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\right)^2\right|_{\theta = 0} E[u + (t+\theta)(u-v)] > 0\tag{*}$$
for any $t$ where $(1-t)u \neq tv$.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, it will follow that
$$\delta E[v](u-v) = \delta E[u](u-v) + \int_0^1 \delta^2 E[u + t(u-v)](u-v)\;dt > 0$$
so $v$ cannot be a critical point of the energy.

To prove (*), we compute that
$$\delta^2 E[u + t(u-v)](u-v) = \int_\Omega |\nabla ((1-t)u + tv)|^2 + p|v|^{-1}((1-t)u + tv)^2\;dx$$
Since the first term is positive for $(1-t)u \neq tv$ and the second term in nonnegative, the result follows.

Comment: Ok, this was my attempt after a long time searching and thinking: As you said, I proved fristly the existence of solution using the energy method. For the uniqueness, I did the following: I proved that the functional $E$ is stricly convex using the definition ($E(tu+(1-t)v) < tE(u) + (1-t)E(v),\ u\neq v, 0<t<1$) and some algebra. From the strictly convexity of $E$, easily follows that if $E$ has a minimum, then is unique. After that, I proved that every weak solution of the problem is actually a minimizer of $E$ on $H_0^1$, therefore we end up with the uniqueness of solution.

Comment: This is what you did (more or less) since positive hessian implies strict. convexity, isn't it?

Comment: Another approach, following the idea of the comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713540/discuss-uniqueness-of-solution-of-delta-u-u-int-omegau2ydy-f, is: define $w= u - v $ where $u$ and $v$ are two solutions, then $w$ satisfies  $$ -\Delta w + |u|^{p-1}u - |v|^{p-1}v  =0 $$, and so $$ \int |\nabla w |^2\ dx + \int w [u|u|^{p-1}-v|v|^{p-1}] \ dx = 0$$ from this follows $$ \int uv(|u|^{p-1} - |v|^{p-1})\ dx = \Vert \nabla w\Vert ^2_{L^2} + \Vert u \Vert^{p-1}_{L^{p-1}} + \Vert v \Vert^{p-1}_{L^{p-1}}  $$ and now I got stucked. I would like to get a contradiction from that.

Comment: @R.N.Marley Yes, it seems like we had the same idea.  Let me think about your second approach, I'll post it as an answer if I figure it out. . .

Comment: @R.N.Marley See my other answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer based on your comment on my other answer.

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are two solutions, and let $w = u-v$.  Then, $w$ solves
$$-\Delta w + |u|^{p-1}u - |v|^{p-1}v = 0$$
Multiplying by $w$ and integrating gives
$$\int |\nabla w|^2 + |u|^{p+1} + |v|^{p+1} - vu|u|^{p-1} - uv|v|^{p-1}\;dx = 0$$
so, rearranging
$$\begin{align*}
 \lVert \nabla w \rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1} + \lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1}  &= \int uv(|u|^{p-1} + |v|^{p-1})\;dx\\
   &\leq \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}\lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p} + \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^p\lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}
\end{align*}$$
by Holder's inequality.  On the other hand, we have the elementary inequality
$$a^{p+1} + b^{p+1} \geq ab^p + a^p b \qquad a,b \geq 0$$
where equality holds only if $a = 0$, $b = 0$, or $a = b$.  Hence,
$$\lVert \nabla w \rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1} + \lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1} \leq \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1} + \lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^{p+1}$$
from which it follows that $\nabla w = 0.$  By the Poincare inequality, $w = 0$ in $H^1$ and $u = v$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks you :)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand the step where you use Hölder. Can you give me some details? As far as I am concerned, Hölder is $$ \int fg \leq \Vert f \Vert_p \Vert g \Vert_q $$ where $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, so what $f$ and $g$ did you pick?

Comment: I'll show you how I got the $\lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}} \lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^p$ term: the other one is analogous.  By the usual Holder inequality,
$$\int u|v|^{p-1} v\;dx \leq \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p+1}} \lVert v|v|^{p-1} \rVert_{L^{\frac{p+1}{p}}}$$
But, the last term is
$$\lVert v|v|^{p-1} \rVert_{L^{\frac{p+1}{p}}} = \left(\int |v|^{p \frac{p+1}{p}}\;dx\right)^{\frac{p}{p+1}} = \left(\left(\int |v|^{p+1}\;dx\right)^{1/p}\right)^p = \lVert v \rVert_{L^{p+1}}^p$$

Comment: I don't really think of it that way, though.  I see it more like a statement that we have an 'iterated Holder' inequality, namely that
$$\int f_1 f_2 \cdots f_p f_{p+1} \;dx \leq \lVert f_1 \rVert_{L^{p+1}}\lVert f_2 \rVert_{L^{p+1}}\cdots \lVert f_p \rVert_{L^{p+1}}\lVert f_{p+1} \rVert_{L^{p+1}}$$
(You can prove this by induction using the ordinary Holder inequality).